# move_uploaded file not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am attempting to do my own manual manual upload of a file in a Wordpress template page. But Im getting this error.

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

```
    $UploadDirectory    =  get_option("siteurl").'/wp-content/uploads/2014/cert-temp/';


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FileInput']['tmp_name'], $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName ))
   {
    // do other stuff
           die('Success! File Uploaded.');
   }else{
    die('error uploading File!');
   }
```

Unfortunately I do not have access to the php.ini file to change settings as we dont manage the servers ourselves, is there any other way of working around this?

I have tried adding `php_value allow_url_fopen On` into the .htaccess file but that didnt work.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't move your file to a http:// address ... use a local filesystem path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use local filesystem path to specifiy target for move_uploaded_file instead of siteurl, 
try

```
 $UploadDirectory    =  WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/2014/cert-temp/';
```